# Symfony 3/Doctrine: Sorting by non-persistent columns

Tags: doctrine, symfony

I have two Models that are related to each other:

```
class Product 
{
    //...

    /**
     * @var Collection<Key>
     * One Product has Many Keys.
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Key", mappedBy="product")
     */
    private $keys;

    public function getKeyNumber() 
    {
         return count($this->keys);
    }

    //...
}

class Key 
{
    //...

    /**
     * @var Product
     *
     * Many Keys have One Product.
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Product", inversedBy="keys")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $product;

    /**
     * @var int
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $product_id;

    //...
}
```

I am able to get the number of Keys with `Product::getKeyNumber()`. Now I'd like to use this value for sorting in the query.

I've tried something like that (DQL Query):

```
SELECT a, COUNT(a.keys) AS keyNumber FROM AppBundle\Entity\Product a ORDER BY keyNumber ASC;
```

which returns:

```
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 18 near 'keys) AS keyNumber': Error: Invalid PathExpression. StateFieldPathExpression or SingleValuedAssociationField expected.
```

When I try:

```
SELECT a FROM AppBundle\Entity\Product a ORDER BY count(a.keys) ASC
```

it says:

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 50: Error: Expected known function, got 'count'
```

Any ideas? :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try doing something like this (just an idea, not a verified code)

```
SELECT a, COUNT(b.id) AS keyNumber FROM AppBundle:Product a JOIN a.keys b ORDER BY keyNumber ASC;
```

As soon as `COUNT()` expects single value field you can explicitly join the keys table and count on something in it (I assume it has ID or you can use whatever is there).

Comment: Seems to work, I just had to add `GROUP BY a.id`. ;) This is the DQL query I ended up with: `SELECT a, COUNT(b.id) AS keyNumber FROM AppBundle:Product a INNER JOIN a.keys b GROUP BY a.id ORDER BY keyNumber ASC`. For some strange reason this does not work: `SELECT a FROM AppBundle:Product a INNER JOIN a.keys b GROUP BY a.id ORDER BY COUNT(b.id) ASC`

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you. The DQL is not so advanced as SQL so I think the case with function in order clause is not implemented (yet?).

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if it has to do with composite keys? I read something about that. I don't know what your key identifier is, but I show `a.id` below. Can you try this:

```
SELECT IDENTITY(a.id), a, COUNT(a.keys) AS keyNumber FROM AppBundle:Product a ORDER BY keyNumber ASC
```

Note, I've reduced AppBundle\Entity\Product to simply AppBundle:Product and got rid of the semicolon at the end.

Let me know if that works, it may not.

Comment: Nope, doesn't work. :/ `[Semantical Error] line 0, col 18 near 'id), a, COUNT(a.keys)': Error: Invalid PathExpression. Must be a SingleValuedAssociationField.` But thanks for your answer. :)